# При нажатии на кнопку, подгружать get_template_part?

Tags: wordpress, ajax

подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать погрузку контента (get_template_part) при нажатии на кнопку (и удаление этого контента, по клику вне него), как должен выглядеть код? Спасибо.

```
<button class="btn" id="btn"></button>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вешаете обработчик клика на кнопку, в нем делаете [XMLHttpRequest](https://learn.javascript.ru/xmlhttprequest), через который вы посылаете запрос на сервер на `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` с указанием `action`. В `functions.php` в папке вашей темы  через хук [wp_ajax_(action)](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/wp_ajax_-action) или [wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)) получаете нужный вам шаблон и отправляете его на страницу.

Comment: [Ошибка молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy/710#710). Для начала предлагаю почитать для чего нужна эта функция, как работает и подумать чем функция отличается от коннента (который необходимо показать/скрыть).